# How to extract multiple columns which is under one column in table

Tags: sql

for example
x_b3_traceid:"a773dea28b76dbda" x_b3_spanid:"9a3872ff020f1342" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"

this 3 under one column.now i want to lo split it and put it as separate column in other table.

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: is it allways traceid, spanid and parentspanid or is there the chance that you have other values in as well?

Comment: and it depends on the engine.  Many have json types that would let you just convert and extract without having to parse the text.